# How access to a single NumPy array in a DICOMDIR file with pydicom?

Tags: python, numpy, dicom, pydicom

I am using DICOM with Python and Pydicom library, when I have used .dcm files I hadn't problems. But I am using DICOMDIR data sets now.

My code is the next:

```
ds = dicom.read_file("dicomdir")
```

I tried to access to the `pixel_array` elements as follows:

```
data = ds.pixel_array
```

And I get the next error: `TypeError: No pixel data found in this dataset.`

The output for `print ds` is more or less the next:

(0004, 1130) File-set ID                         CS: 'GEMS_11_10_111'
(0004, 1200) Offset of the First Directory Recor UL: 412
(0004, 1202) Offset of the Last Directory Record UL: 412
(0004, 1212) File-set Consistency Flag           US: 0
(0004, 1220)  Directory Record Sequence   7 item(s) ---- 
   (0004, 1400) Offset of the Next Directory Record UL: 0
   (0004, 1410) Record In-use Flag                  US: 65535
   (0004, 1420) Offset of Referenced Lower-Level Di UL: 558
   (0004, 1430) Directory Record Type               CS: 'PATIENT'
   (0008, 0005) Specific Character Set              CS: 'ISO_IR 100'
   (0010, 0010) Patient's Name                      PN: '------------------'
   (0010, 0020) Patient ID                          LO: '246992'
   (0010, 0030) Patient's Birth Date                DA: '19630523'
   (0010, 0040) Patient's Sex                       CS: 'F'

---

(0004, 1400) Offset of the Next Directory Record UL: 0
   (0004, 1410) Record In-use Flag                  US: 65535
   (0004, 1420) Offset of Referenced Lower-Level Di UL: 800
   (0004, 1430) Directory Record Type               CS: 'STUDY'
   (0008, 0005) Specific Character Set              CS: 'ISO_IR 100'
   (0008, 0020) Study Date                          DA: '20111011'
   (0008, 0030) Study Time                          TM: '151535.000000'
   (0008, 0050) Accession Number                    SH: '1009819901'
   (0008, 1030) Study Description                   LO: 'MG CONVENCIONAL'
   (0020, 000d) Study Instance UID                  UI: 1.2.840.113564.9.1.2005121220021252.20110608105548.21009819901
   (0020, 0010) Study ID                            SH: '1009819901'

---

(0004, 1400) Offset of the Next Directory Record UL: 0
   (0004, 1410) Record In-use Flag                  US: 65535
   (0004, 1420) Offset of Referenced Lower-Level Di UL: 968
   (0004, 1430) Directory Record Type               CS: 'SERIES'
   (0008, 0005) Specific Character Set              CS: 'ISO_IR 100'
   (0008, 0060) Modality                            CS: 'MG'
   (0008, 103e) Series Description                  LO: 'Screen Save'
   (0020, 000e) Series Instance UID                 UI: 1.2.840.113619.2.144.2347322947.2192645372.5
   (0020, 0011) Series Number                       IS: '354'

---

(0004, 1400) Offset of the Next Directory Record UL: 1298
   (0004, 1410) Record In-use Flag                  US: 65535
   (0004, 1420) Offset of Referenced Lower-Level Di UL: 0
   (0004, 1430) Directory Record Type               CS: 'IMAGE'
   (0004, 1500) Referenced File ID                  CS: ['DICOM', 'PA1', 'ST1', 'SE1', 'IM1']
   (0004, 1510) Referenced SOP Class UID in File    UI: Secondary Capture Image Storage
   (0004, 1511) Referenced SOP Instance UID in File UI: 1.2.840.113619.2.144.44653394.14990.1318380911.86
   (0004, 1512) Referenced Transfer Syntax UID in F UI: Explicit VR Little Endian
   (0008, 0005) Specific Character Set              CS: 'ISO_IR 100'
   (0008, 0008) Image Type                          CS: 'DERIVED'
   (0008, 0023) Content Date                        DA: '20111011'
   (0008, 0033) Content Time                        TM: '151909.000000'
   (0020, 0013) Instance Number                     IS: '8844'
   (0028, 0010) Rows                                US: 2298
   (0028, 0011) Columns                             US: 1980
   (0028, 1052) Rescale Intercept                   DS: '0'
   (0028, 1053) Rescale Slope                       DS: '1'

---

The last part is repeated four times. I have 4 images in my DICOMDIR dataset.

Do you know how access to the field with the Numpy Array for each image?

Comment: Noticed that you asked the same question in the [pydicom user forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pydicom/TR2nl6_JRtM). For completeness, it would be great if you could provide a copy of this answer here on SO.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson is ok, you have are quite right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I received an answer in Pydicom User Forum by Suever:

DICOMDIR files do not contain any pixel information but rather basic header information along with the path to each file in the dataset. In order to get the pixel data from each of the images, you'll have to traverse the dicomdir dataset to get the filepaths to the individual dicom files (relative to the current directory) and then load the pixel data from each of the individual dicom files.

A simple way to do this would be (there may be better ways)

```
    ds = dicom.read_file("dicomdir")
    pixel_data = list()
    for record in ds.DirectoryRecordSequence:
        if record.DirectoryRecordType == "IMAGE":
        # Extract the relative path to the DICOM file
            path = os.path.join(*record.ReferencedFileID)
            dcm = dicom.read_file(path)

            # Now get your image data
            pixel_data.append(dcm.pixel_array)
```

It works ;)